# .htaccess not excluding PNG files

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

The problem It's that when I try to load the favicon It does not show. I thought that I could exclude the .png files but this also does not seem to work. Is the regex wrong?

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(app\.php|robots\.txt|imgs|logos|\.png)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**base**: (the CSS loads ok with this base)

```
<base href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
```

**path**:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/imgs/logos/android-chrome-512x512.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

**Folder structure**: https://prnt.sc/1a1gzsh

Comment: Yes the regex is wrong. Better test it before you put it in. So can you please explain the regular expression pattern you have in there in your own words, character per character?

Comment: I’m pretty certain the first conditional block always wins, so the second never fires, unless I’m missing something?